How to use lucid cardano with angular?
Lucid cardano import fails whatever way I try to add it to angular project. This is currently my best attempt, but still a failed one.
import {Blockfrost, Lucid} from "lucid-cardano";

    let a = await Lucid.new(
      new Blockfrost(
        "ApiAddress",
        "projectId",
      ),
      "network"
    );

I enabled custom webpack builder in angular.json:
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",

and setup my "webpack.config.js" file like this:
module.exports = {
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    layers: true
  }
};

All according to the latest documentation:
https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid
But still I receive this error:

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
scandir ''

I did it all on clear angular project. Please help.
What can I be missing?
